# Performance effect of using print statements in Python script

Tags: python, console, text-files

I have a Python script that process a huge text file (with around 4 millon lines) and writes the data into two separate files.

I have added a print statement, which outputs a string for every line for debugging. I want to know how bad it could be from the performance perspective?

If it is going to very bad, I can remove the debugging line.

**Edit**

It turns out that having a print statement for every line in a file with 4 million lines is increasing the time way too much.

Comment: `timeit` http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: It will be slower as you are having to perform a large number of prints, any extra processing is going to incur some performance penalty.

Comment: Send `item` to a socket queue : the program will finish the writes first, and the console from the socket will print the output with a lag.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Tried doing it in a very simple script just for fun, the difference is quite staggering:

In large.py:

```
target =  open('target.txt', 'w')

for item in xrange(4000000):
    target.write(str(item)+'\n')
    print item
```

Timing it:

```
[gp@imdev1 /tmp]$ time python large.py
real    1m51.690s
user    0m10.531s
sys     0m6.129s

gp@imdev1 /tmp]$ ls -lah target.txt 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gp gp 30M Nov  8 16:06 target.txt
```

Now running the same with "print" commented out:

```
gp@imdev1 /tmp]$ time python large.py 
real    0m2.584s
user    0m2.536s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Comment: And when you comment out the write, leave in the print, and run with `> target.txt` ?

Comment: @Tim: Oddly enough it worked faster, but it could be my machine is less busier than it was when I ran it earlier, don't have time right now to run it many times to use more sound statistical approach. [gp@imdev1 /tmp]$ time python large.py > target.txt 

real 0m1.954s
user 0m1.897s
sys 0m0.049s

Comment: redirecting stdout to a file will be much faster, in fact you can direct to a file and open the file in an editor in less time than it takes to spew a large amount of io to the screen.

Comment: @GSP Thanks. It looks like, I should remove the print statements.

Comment: I was wondering as well if having a verbose option that checks a bool as to whether or not to print hurts time much. Using `if False: print item` I had it run in **1.417s** and without any print it ran in **1.357s**.

Comment: you could also print every 1,000th item, using modulo: `for i,item in enumerate(range(4_000_000)): if i%1_000==0: print(i, item)`, to show progress

Answer (score 6):

Yes it affects performance.
I wrote a small program to demonstrate-

```
import time
start_time=time.time()
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            print(i,j,k)
print(time.time()-start_time)
input()
```

The time measured was-160.2812204496765
Then I replaced the print statement by pass. The results were shocking. The measured time without print was- 0.26517701148986816.