# convert extracted data from a link to dataframe using beautifulsoup and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

the script extract data from the list of urls using **beautifulsoup** and convert the data into a dataframe in order to export as excel file.

the problem is when i try to convert the data into dataframe it display the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py", line 144, in <module>
    scrap_website()
  File "f:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py", line 88, in scrap_website
    convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd)
  File "f:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py", line 98, in convert_to_dataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd,columns=["link","location","Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Employment_Type","Monthly_Salary_Range","Number_of_Vacancies","Career_Level","Years_of_Experience","Residence_Location","Gender","Nationality","Degree","Age"])
  File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 509, in __init__
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 524, in to_arrays
    return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
  File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 567, in _list_to_arrays
    raise ValueError(e) from e
ValueError: 15 columns passed, passed data had 13 columns
```

my question is how to fix this error ?

**I think if the extracted data is empty i can extract it and display NaN or null**

## CODE:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




def scrap_website():
    url_list = ["https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/","https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/head-chef-jobs/","https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-sous-chef-jobs/"]
    for url in url_list:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"lxml")

        links = []
        for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
            if a['href'] not in links:
                links.append("https://www.bayt.com"+ a['href'])
        joineddd = []

        for link in links:
            s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
            alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
            
            alldd.insert(0,link)
            joineddd.append(alldd)
            
            print("-" * 80)
            
        print("Web Crawling is Done for  {}".format(url))
        convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd) 


def remove_unwanted_cols(dataset, cols):
    for col in cols:
        del dataset[col]
    return dataset

def convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd):
    df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd,columns=["link","location","Company_Industry","Company_Type",
    "Job_Role","Employment_Type","Monthly_Salary_Range","Number_of_Vacancies","Career_Level",
    "Years_of_Experience","Residence_Location","Gender","Nationality","Degree","Age"])
    df = remove_unwanted_cols(df, ["Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Number_of_Vacancies"])

    df_to_excel = df.to_excel(r"F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx", index = False, header=True)    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrap_website()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code on my machine, but I didn't get any errors. But I have detected some performance issues in your code. First of all, please stop printing stuff on screen in every loop just because you want to know if it is working or not. That is a huge problem in performance: [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288185/performance-effect-of-using-print-statements-in-python-script)

If you really wanna know that your code is working, print it in every 100 loops. Like this:

```
for index,link in enumerate(links):
        if index % 100 == 0 and index != 0:
            print(f"Scraping {index}. page.")
        s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
```

And the error is pretty self-explanatory, you had 15 columns, but instead of giving 15 you gave 13. So that means some of your values got a null value at the end of your script in **convert_to_dataFrame()**. Please before you insert any value, check if the element that you are looking for exists in some way during scraping. It can be implemented in many ways. Or you can create a function called **clear_dataframe()** and pass the list in this function at the end of the scraping process.